# Does overstaying on a previous visit result in automatic refusal?

Tags: uk-visa, overstay

I have previously held a student visa in the UK in which I overstayed for less than 30 days (7 days). This overstay occured less than 1 year ago and I left voluntarily and with my own funds. I now wish to apply for a Youth-Mobility (tier 5) visa which would allow me to work and live in the UK for a period of 2 years. Would my application be automatically refused if I were to apply? How likely would it be that I would be granted the visa? I am an Australian citizen. I am able to meet all the other point based criteria for the YMS visa.

Answer (score 1):

Would my application be automatically refused if I were to apply?

- No. An overstay such as you describe would not trigger an automatic refusal https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/general-grounds-for-refusal-considering-entry-clearance

How likely would it be that I would be granted the visa?

- No-one can answer that with any certainty.